# How to insert c++ style #define'd (literal) text in a VIM key mapping

Tags: vim

For example, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
#define SAVE "<C-o>:call MySaveFn()<CR>"
inoremap <F2> {SAVE}....
inoremap <F3> {SAVE}....
```

Basically to make all my inoremaps look more compact. (The only alternative I see is assign keys for each of these equivalent defines and do a recursive imap instead of inoremap, which I don't want to do.)

Answer (score 1):

You could define a variable and then `:execute` your expression.

For instance:

```
:let s:save = '<c-o>:call <sid>MySaveFn()<cr>'
:exe 'inoremap <F2> '.s:save
```

Comment: I want to be able to add more mappings in place of the '....' in my code snippet in the question. Can I do that here?

Comment: Of course, put them in a string, and concatenate it to the expression to be executed -> `:exe 'inoremap <F2> '.s:save.'some other stuff'`.

Comment: Thanks for the input!